# Did the Hawaiiians get tattoos for what nā ʻaumākua they believed that they would reincarnate as?

Tags: hawaii

I'm in the process of overananlyzing the film *Moana*. During my research, I discovered that the Polynesians *did* actually believe that an ancestor could reincarnate - as an animal, another person, a rock... These were called [nā ʻaumākua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aumakua). In the *Moana* film, [Grandma Tala](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Gramma_Tala) gets a tattoo of the animal that she believes that she'll reincarnate as (a sting ray, as it happens).

**Did the Polynesians actually get tattoos of what animal they believed that they would reincarnate as?**

Comment: As I understand it, the tattoos are of *their* aumakua, not an aumakua they themselves might become.

Comment: Freaking love this question! Sadly, honesty forces me to point out that it might be right in the sweet spot of the Mythology stack. OTOH, I believe its on-topic here as well, and we're probably more active than they are.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I've asked a couple questions on Mythology.SE the last couple days. I considered asking this there, but decided on here because it's asking about what they actually did, as opposed to what they believed. And yeah, History.SE is more active than Mythology.SE ;) Also, thanks! :D